# Accessing a nested class from another nested dataclass

Tags: python, python-3.7, inner-classes, data-class

Now the following code works perfectly with Python 3.7

```py
class A:
    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            print("B")

    class C:
        def __init__(self):
            self.b = A.B()

def main():
    a = A.C()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It prints a `B` on the screen.

However, with a small modification that tries to introduce dataclass, the code cannot run well.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

class A:
    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            print("B")

    @dataclass
    class C:
        b = A.B()

def main():
    a = A.C()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Python reports -- for `b = A.B()` -- `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue to achieve the same result with dataclass? And why does it say `name 'A' is not defined`?

Comment: Just unnest your class, and if you really need that namespacing, just add `A.C = C`. Note, your dataclass is not equivalent to what you had before.

Answer (score 3):

A class object is not created until the end of body of a `class` statement is reached, which is why your class `A` cannot be referenced while it is still being defined. Referencing `A` inside the `__init__` method, on the other hand, is valid because the class `A` is already defined when the `__init__` method is called.

You can instead use `typing.TypeVar` to define a forward-referencing type `A.B` for `b`, and assign to it a default value of a `field` with a `default_factory` function that returns an instance of `A.B` when called:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import TypeVar

class A:
    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            print("B")

    @dataclass
    class C:
        b: TypeVar('A.B') = field(default_factory=lambda: A.B())

def main():
    a = A.C()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This outputs:

```
B
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can I ask for some clarification: What do you mean by `a class is being defined`? In both programs, `C` should be part of `A`. Why is it that calling `__init__` method of `C` in the first program is thought to be done **after** `A`'s definition, while specifying  `b = A.B()` in `C` in the second program is thought to be done **within** `A`'s definition?

Comment: `class` is an instruction in python. It's not a declaration like in other languages

Comment: Thanks! But frankly I am still (or maybe even more) confused. Then what's the difference between an *instruction* and a *declaration* in this context? I have background in C/C++. If you would like to draw any comparison I am more than happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to defer its initialisation until `class A` is defined and available, without touching the generated `__init__`:

```
@dataclass
class C:
    b: TypeVar('A.B') = field(init=False)

def __post_init__(self):
    self.b = A.B()
```

Please refer to the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

Comment: This is good unless you're defining `C.b` in the auto-generated `__init__`, i.e. `C(b=A.B(foo))`.